# Mongodb Sorting Desc for _id field very slow

Tags: python, mongodb, performance, sorting, pymongo

I have a mongodb database which has 30 million Dictionary and Each day of month has 1 million rows so all of document count 30x1=30 Million, database just has data for 1 month and i want to list and sort desc records of between 2018-07-01 and 2018-07-03 so i have 2 million rows between of that two days My each collection like below:

```
{
"_id":"5c66cf5b67011aa76ca597b6",
"timestamp":"2018-07-01 15:45:37.000",
"category":"category_1"
}
```

I added sorting desc index for timestamp column

When i try sort asc i get response 0,1 seconds but i try sort desc i am getting response 702 seconds

I am building python

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime
import time
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.MongoBencmarkTestDB

indicator_collections = db.IndicatorCollections

dstart = datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1,0, 0, 0)
dfinish = datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 3,0, 0, 0)

for indicator_collection in indicator_collections.find({
    "$and":
        [
            {
                "timestamp": {"$lte": dfinish, "$gte": dstart}
            },
        ]

}).sort([("_id", -1)]).skip(0).limit(1000):
    print(indicator_collection['_id'])
```

When i explain _id field for sorting desc:

```
db.IndicatorCollections.find().sort({_id : -1}).explain()
```

Getting response:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "MongoBencmarkTestDB.IndicatorCollections",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {

        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "_id_",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "_id" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : true,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "backward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "_id" : [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "reterius-pc-MacBook-Pro.local",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "4.0.3",
        "gitVersion" : "7ea530946fa7880364d88c8d8b6026bbc9ffa48c"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

My indexes:

```
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "MongoBencmarkTestDB.IndicatorCollections"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "timestamp" : -1
        },
        "name" : "timestamp_-1",
        "ns" : "MongoBencmarkTestDB.IndicatorCollections"
    }
]
```

I want to get response quickly because its very important.

Comment: what indices do you exactly have? pls print them (db.collection.getIndexes())

Comment: @RichieK   [
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "MongoBencmarkTestDB.IndicatorCollections"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "timestamp" : -1
        },
        "name" : "timestamp_-1",
        "ns" : "MongoBencmarkTestDB.IndicatorCollections"
    }
]

Comment: i though you maybe used compound indices, because on single indices the direction does not matter. but well I guess you need a compound index then on timestamp and _id field with your desired directions. {tiimestamp: 1, _id : -1}

Comment: note that the field you are sorting by has to be the last field in the index

Comment: @RichieK i am not using compound indices, i show my index below. Just i want to sort desc for _id field. My indexes: [
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "MongoBencmarkTestDB.IndicatorCollections"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "timestamp" : -1
        },
        "name" : "timestamp_-1",
        "ns" : "MongoBencmarkTestDB.IndicatorCollections"
    }
]

Comment: and your simple desc sort is also slow without query? its IXSCAN so i thought that should not take a while...

Comment: so if your python script is slow, you need a compound index but I dont think that your simple explained query is slow...

Comment: @RichieK when i try without query like so : indicator_collections.find().sort([("_id", -1)]).skip(0).limit(1000) its very very quickly its just 0.8 seconds. Whats problem i dont know.

Comment: As I said, you need a compound Index. Becaus on one hand it needs the index to match fast your timestamp but on the other hand you also need an index for sorting. And you cant combine two indices. Maybe thats your understanding problem. For matching on one field and sorting on another you need one compound index.

Comment: so run 

db.collection.createIndex( { timestamp: 1, _id: -1 } ) and check again if its faster (as it should be)

Answer (score 0):

So you need to run db.collection.createIndex( { timestamp: 1, _id: -1 } ) and check again if its faster (as it should be). As I have written before, Mongo uses just one index for a query, and if there is no index with timestamp and descending _id field, it is slow.

Comment: i added that : db.collection.createIndex( { timestamp: 1, _id: -1 } ) . But no changes, its now slower than before. Response time 491 seconds. Its not solved

Comment: then can you show the explain of the query resulting from your pythonscript? did you miss some parts of the query? at least there is some comma in your snippet which should not be there. so if you are also querying category you also needd to add that to your index...

Comment: I explained my query on below as answer.

Answer (score 0):

When i explained my query on pymongo result is below:

{'queryPlanner': {'plannerVersion': 1, 'namespace': 'MongoBencmarkTestDB.IndicatorCollections', 'indexFilterSet': False, 'parsedQuery': {'$and': [{'timestamp': {'$lte': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 3, 0, 0)}}, {'timestamp': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 0, 0)}}]}, 'winningPlan': {'stage': 'SORT', 'sortPattern': {'_id': -1}, 'limitAmount': 1000, 'inputStage': {'stage': 'SORT_KEY_GENERATOR', 'inputStage': {'stage': 'FETCH', 'inputStage': {'stage': 'IXSCAN', 'keyPattern': {'timestamp': -1.0}, 'indexName': 'timestamp_-1', 'isMultiKey': False, 'multiKeyPaths': {'timestamp': []}, 'isUnique': False, 'isSparse': False, 'isPartial': False, 'indexVersion': 2, 'direction': 'forward', 'indexBounds': {'timestamp': ['[new Date(1530576000000), new Date(1530403200000)]']}}}}}, 'rejectedPlans': [{'stage': 'SORT', 'sortPattern': {'_id': -1}, 'limitAmount': 1000, 'inputStage': {'stage': 'SORT_KEY_GENERATOR', 'inputStage': {'stage': 'FETCH', 'inputStage': {'stage': 'IXSCAN', 'keyPattern': {'timestamp': 1.0, '_id': -1.0}, 'indexName': 'timestamp_1__id_-1', 'isMultiKey': False, 'multiKeyPaths': {'timestamp': [], '_id': []}, 'isUnique': False, 'isSparse': False, 'isPartial': False, 'indexVersion': 2, 'direction': 'forward', 'indexBounds': {'timestamp': ['[new Date(1530403200000), new Date(1530576000000)]'], '_id': ['[MaxKey, MinKey]']}}}}}, {'stage': 'LIMIT', 'limitAmount': 1000, 'inputStage': {'stage': 'FETCH', 'filter': {'$and': [{'timestamp': {'$lte': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 3, 0, 0)}}, {'timestamp': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 0, 0)}}]}, 'inputStage': {'stage': 'IXSCAN', 'keyPattern': {'_id': 1}, 'indexName': '*id*', 'isMultiKey': False, 'multiKeyPaths': {'_id': []}, 'isUnique': True, 'isSparse': False, 'isPartial': False, 'indexVersion': 2, 'direction': 'backward', 'indexBounds': {'_id': ['[MaxKey, MinKey]']}}}}]}, 'executionStats': {'executionSuccess': True, 'nReturned': 1000, 'executionTimeMillis': 552284, 'totalKeysExamined': 2000000, 'totalDocsExamined': 2000000, 'executionStages': {'stage': 'SORT', 'nReturned': 1000, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 137134, 'works': 2001003, 'advanced': 1000, 'needTime': 2000002, 'needYield': 0, 'saveState': 53750, 'restoreState': 53750, 'isEOF': 1, 'invalidates': 0, 'sortPattern': {'_id': -1}, 'memUsage': 9056307, 'memLimit': 33554432, 'limitAmount': 1000, 'inputStage': {'stage': 'SORT_KEY_GENERATOR', 'nReturned': 2000000, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 134910, 'works': 2000002, 'advanced': 2000000, 'needTime': 1, 'needYield': 0, 'saveState': 53750, 'restoreState': 53750, 'isEOF': 1, 'invalidates': 0, 'inputStage': {'stage': 'FETCH', 'nReturned': 2000000, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 132229, 'works': 2000001, 'advanced': 2000000, 'needTime': 0, 'needYield': 0, 'saveState': 53750, 'restoreState': 53750, 'isEOF': 1, 'invalidates': 0, 'docsExamined': 2000000, 'alreadyHasObj': 0, 'inputStage': {'stage': 'IXSCAN', 'nReturned': 2000000, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 2077, 'works': 2000001, 'advanced': 2000000, 'needTime': 0, 'needYield': 0, 'saveState': 53750, 'restoreState': 53750, 'isEOF': 1, 'invalidates': 0, 'keyPattern': {'timestamp': -1.0}, 'indexName': 'timestamp_-1', 'isMultiKey': False, 'multiKeyPaths': {'timestamp': []}, 'isUnique': False, 'isSparse': False, 'isPartial': False, 'indexVersion': 2, 'direction': 'forward', 'indexBounds': {'timestamp': ['[new Date(1530576000000), new Date(1530403200000)]']}, 'keysExamined': 2000000, 'seeks': 1, 'dupsTested': 0, 'dupsDropped': 0, 'seenInvalidated': 0}}}}, 'allPlansExecution': [{'nReturned': 101, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 137134, 'totalKeysExamined': 2000000, 'totalDocsExamined': 2000000, 'executionStages': {'stage': 'SORT', 'nReturned': 101, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 137134, 'works': 2000103, 'advanced': 101, 'needTime': 2000002, 'needYield': 0, 'saveState': 53742, 'restoreState': 53742, 'isEOF': 0, 'invalidates': 0, 'sortPattern': {'_id': -1}, 'memUsage': 9056307, 'memLimit': 33554432, 'limitAmount': 1000, 'inputStage': {'stage': 'SORT_KEY_GENERATOR', 'nReturned': 2000000, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 134910, 'works': 2000002, 'advanced': 2000000, 'needTime': 1, 'needYield': 0, 'saveState': 53742, 'restoreState': 53742, 'isEOF': 1, 'invalidates': 0, 'inputStage': {'stage': 'FETCH', 'nReturned': 2000000, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 132229, 'works': 2000001, 'advanced': 2000000, 'needTime': 0, 'needYield': 0, 'saveState': 53742, 'restoreState': 53742, 'isEOF': 1, 'invalidates': 0, 'docsExamined': 2000000, 'alreadyHasObj': 0, 'inputStage': {'stage': 'IXSCAN', 'nReturned': 2000000, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 2077, 'works': 2000001, 'advanced': 2000000, 'needTime': 0, 'needYield': 0, 'saveState': 53742, 'restoreState': 53742, 'isEOF': 1, 'invalidates': 0, 'keyPattern': {'timestamp': -1.0}, 'indexName': 'timestamp_-1', 'isMultiKey': False, 'multiKeyPaths': {'timestamp': []}, 'isUnique': False, 'isSparse': False, 'isPartial': False, 'indexVersion': 2, 'direction': 'forward', 'indexBounds': {'timestamp': ['[new Date(1530576000000), new Date(1530403200000)]']}, 'keysExamined': 2000000, 'seeks': 1, 'dupsTested': 0, 'dupsDropped': 0, 'seenInvalidated': 0}}}}}, {'nReturned': 101, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 286826, 'totalKeysExamined': 2000000, 'totalDocsExamined': 2000000, 'executionStages': {'stage': 'SORT', 'nReturned': 101, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 286826, 'works': 2000103, 'advanced': 101, 'needTime': 2000002, 'needYield': 0, 'saveState': 53750, 'restoreState': 53750, 'isEOF': 0, 'invalidates': 0, 'sortPattern': {'_id': -1}, 'memUsage': 9056307, 'memLimit': 33554432, 'limitAmount': 1000, 'inputStage': {'stage': 'SORT_KEY_GENERATOR', 'nReturned': 2000000, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 284785, 'works': 2000002, 'advanced': 2000000, 'needTime': 1, 'needYield': 0, 'saveState': 53750, 'restoreState': 53750, 'isEOF': 1, 'invalidates': 0, 'inputStage': {'stage': 'FETCH', 'nReturned': 2000000, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 128225, 'works': 2000001, 'advanced': 2000000, 'needTime': 0, 'needYield': 0, 'saveState': 53750, 'restoreState': 53750, 'isEOF': 1, 'invalidates': 0, 'docsExamined': 2000000, 'alreadyHasObj': 0, 'inputStage': {'stage': 'IXSCAN', 'nReturned': 2000000, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 1579, 'works': 2000001, 'advanced': 2000000, 'needTime': 0, 'needYield': 0, 'saveState': 53750, 'restoreState': 53750, 'isEOF': 1, 'invalidates': 0, 'keyPattern': {'timestamp': 1.0, '_id': -1.0}, 'indexName': 'timestamp_1__id_-1', 'isMultiKey': False, 'multiKeyPaths': {'timestamp': [], '_id': []}, 'isUnique': False, 'isSparse': False, 'isPartial': False, 'indexVersion': 2, 'direction': 'forward', 'indexBounds': {'timestamp': ['[new Date(1530403200000), new Date(1530576000000)]'], '_id': ['[MaxKey, MinKey]']}, 'keysExamined': 2000000, 'seeks': 1, 'dupsTested': 0, 'dupsDropped': 0, 'seenInvalidated': 0}}}}}, {'nReturned': 0, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 126373, 'totalKeysExamined': 2000103, 'totalDocsExamined': 2000103, 'executionStages': {'stage': 'LIMIT', 'nReturned': 0, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 126373, 'works': 2000103, 'advanced': 0, 'needTime': 2000103, 'needYield': 0, 'saveState': 53750, 'restoreState': 53750, 'isEOF': 0, 'invalidates': 0, 'limitAmount': 1000, 'inputStage': {'stage': 'FETCH', 'filter': {'$and': [{'timestamp': {'$lte': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 3, 0, 0)}}, {'timestamp': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 0, 0)}}]}, 'nReturned': 0, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 126232, 'works': 2000103, 'advanced': 0, 'needTime': 2000103, 'needYield': 0, 'saveState': 53750, 'restoreState': 53750, 'isEOF': 0, 'invalidates': 0, 'docsExamined': 2000103, 'alreadyHasObj': 0, 'inputStage': {'stage': 'IXSCAN', 'nReturned': 2000103, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 2205, 'works': 2000103, 'advanced': 2000103, 'needTime': 0, 'needYield': 0, 'saveState': 53750, 'restoreState': 53750, 'isEOF': 0, 'invalidates': 0, 'keyPattern': {'_id': 1}, 'indexName': '*id*', 'isMultiKey': False, 'multiKeyPaths': {'_id': []}, 'isUnique': True, 'isSparse': False, 'isPartial': False, 'indexVersion': 2, 'direction': 'backward', 'indexBounds': {'_id': ['[MaxKey, MinKey]']}, 'keysExamined': 2000103, 'seeks': 1, 'dupsTested': 0, 'dupsDropped': 0, 'seenInvalidated': 0}}}}]}, 'serverInfo': {'host': 'reterius-pc-MacBook-Pro.local', 'port': 27017, 'version': '4.0.3', 'gitVersion': '7ea530946fa7880364d88c8d8b6026bbc9ffa48c'}, 'ok': 1.0}

Comment: no sure why but the winning query did not use your compound index and therefore has no index for sorting. do you need the single index for timestamp? maybe try delete this index. but i really dont know why it is not using compound index...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497433/why-mongodb-different-query-plans-show-different-nreturned-value at least explains a bit...

Comment: hm i tried that locally and queryplanner still prefers to not use that compound index... hmm.. not sure why

Comment: @RichieK its very interesting, i dont know

Answer (score 0):

Question is few months old now, but if you still need the answer(or if someone else does)

You are doing sorting on field "_id".

But it is the second field (non-prefix) of your index `{ timestamp: 1, _id: -1 }`. A sorting on non-prefix index won't be using the index, and that is why your sort isn't using your compound index.

Change your index to `{ _id: -1, timestamp: 1}`, and then check if your explain query uses the index. Alternatively, you can also try sorting on "timestamp" field, if it solves your purpose.

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index